# What can someone do with a stolen wallet for a few seconds?

Tags: united-kingdom, fraud, identity-theft

I was recently in the gym and left my keys, phone and wallet together on top of my jumper. I took my eyes off of them for maybe 5 seconds, which I now know is too long, whilst I went and got some more weights.

I came back and my wallet was missing. I searched for it for maybe 30 seconds before asking some guys if they had seen anything. They said they handed it in at the front desk so I went and collected it immediately. My debit card, drivers license, and cash were all in there and nothing looked out of place.

All of this happened within 30-40 seconds and I was incredibly suspicious so when I got home I immediately contacted my bank to cancel my card and ordered a new one.

So my questions are:

1. What can someone do with my wallet for 30-40 seconds?
2. Is there anything that they can still do now I have cancelled my card?

Comment: I once had a clip with a credit card, my health insurance card, and a $20 fall out of my cycling saddlebag.  I retraced and found it, out of my control for about 15 minutes.  It was on my house's street.  The credit card was still in it, the $20 was gone.  I thought that was fair.

Comment: Does the gym have CCTV?

Comment: In 30-40 seconds, someone would check your wallet to find owner's information so that they can return it back to you, and when they can't find owner's info in the wallet they would hand it over to the security desk.

Comment: Open-ended hypothetical questions such as your question 1 are off topic. Also list questions/questions where all answers are equally valid ("tell me 10 things I can do with a...") are off topic for most SE sites.

Comment: @AjeetShah In the case explained to the OP I would consider it a bad decission to open the wallet even if only to get the owner's information. If you "get caught" in the act the action can easily be misinterpreted, or the owner may have information they do not want the public to see. I think it is better to deliver it immediately to security desk. If no such thing is possible, openly state to several people that you have found the wallet and, if nobody claims ownership, then open it in front of witnesses that to get the information.

Comment: @SJuan76 OP didn't ask "What to do after finding someone's wallet? " but they asked "What can someone do with my wallet in 30-40 seconds?". So i presented a case about what a person might do with someone's wallet before handing it over to the security (in a short period of time). YES, your commmet is a good addition in case someone tried to learn "what to do after finding someone's wallet?" from my comment.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If I’m prepared and have a camera ready I can take photos of all your cards and note the security codes on the back. With that I can make payments with your card.

A stupid criminal could use that to have expensive things delivered to their home, a clever criminal would figure out how to rob you without getting caught. I could make lots of donations to good causes.

But once your card is cancelled, nothing they can do.

Comment: I did think they could take photos but this may look incredibly suspicious doing it in what was a crowded gym - although if they have the audacity to steal a wallet then this might not be unreasonable to assume.

Comment: Newer cards seem to make this even simpler: the number and the security code might appear *only* on the back, necessitating only one picture of the card to provide all the relevant information.

Comment: Someone with a good memory could remember the name and numbers.

Comment: @DJClayworth I would hope someone with a memory that good could find much better ways to make money than stealing wallets. ;)

Comment: @TTT I can remember a credit card number pretty easily. It's not a very profitable talent, unfortunately.

Comment: @Kat - Hehe- maybe not. Though I'd say memorizing a 23 digit random number (though 5 of the numbers aren't completely random) in say 10-15 seconds means your brain is such that you could do something useful with it. Maybe clean up in 7 card stud? :D

Comment: This is a ridiculous answer.   A group of guys at a gym took pictures of wallet contents and brought it to the front desk in 30 seconds.   Come on dude.

Comment: @blankip The answer addresses "what could someone do in a few seconds" not "what definitely happened in this specific scenario".

Comment: @TTT - You'd hope. :-) But it's easy enough to get someone's credit card number via other means. Then all you're doing is remembering which security code goes with which card number. Those little three-digits codes are much easier to remember (along with, say, the last two digits of the card number to know which goes with which), easily and quickly written down without a camera, etc. Did it happen? Probably not. But it's at least plausible. :-)

Comment: Is that really the case for your cards? At least for me, having my card data is not really sufficient to steal any substantial amount; you need either the actual card chip for physical payments, or 3Dsecure (essentially, internetbank verification) for any nontrivial online payments.

Answer (score 57):

Don't be so paranoid! An ill-wisher would just have pocketed your wallet. Somebody did you a good turn by handing it in to the desk, so that nobody else would be tempted. Be thankful and stop worrying!

Comment: If I took the cards, the owner would block them immediately, before I can use them. If I just record the numbers, there is a good chance that I can use these numbers for some time.

Comment: @gnasher729 On the other hand, the owner can't block the cash, and this wallet was handed in with its cash intact. It's an unlikely thief that would leave the cash but still commit credit card fraud.

Comment: @JBentley - Ah, yes, but you see that's all part of the con! "Whoever it  was left the cash, so I guess they didn't grab the card information..." :-) (Did it happen? Probably not.)

Comment: The thing that raised my suspicion in the first place was that it was with my other possessions so I'd think they would either hand all of them in or none.

Comment: Some people might not even notice for sure if 20-50% of the cash from the wallet was gone.

Comment: I once went to a drive through restaurant in a different city. They took the card out of my sight for about 30 seconds. Around a year later, I had hundreds of dollars charged to my card in that city. The person is not being paranoid.

Comment: @Evorlor: Your anecdote kind of supports my point. Every time you use your card, you are taking the risk that they will skim your number at the till. You have to accept that risk if you want to use your card at all. On the other hand, the risk that somebody skims your number _and then hands in your wallet_ is small by comparison. A genuine malefactor would replace the wallet where they found it, no?

Comment: This is not answering his question!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder _"Whoever it was left the cash, so I guess they didn't grab the card information..."_ - In that case, the conman could have done even better by not bringing the wallet to the front desk, but by leaving it in its original place ;)

Comment: @marcelm - Quite!

Comment: @Brondahl I think TonyK is pointing out that this is an XY problem. I happen to think it's a great answer.

Answer (score 21):

Everything is risk vs reward.

You left your wallet on gym floor.   A group of guys saw it and returned it to the front desk.   I have two things to say - I managed a Golds Gym for a while and I also have worked out at a gym probably 200 days a year the past 25 years (started young).

Your example is super super frequent.   It is also sometimes annoying I often would have my phone wallet keys and I am super setting, walk away for 1 min (like 20 feet away) and boom my stuff is in the front desk.   There is almost zero chance - let's say .00001% that a group of guys would take your wallet, take any piece of info from it, and then return it to front desk in 30 secs.   The gym would probably have them on camera.   Unless these guys seemed EXTREMELY suspicious I would thank them (even though it is annoying) and move on with your life.

The other side of this is you cancel all of your cards and everything in your wallet, call up the card companies get new stuff, and then they send everything to you.   There is a far far far greater chance than the .00001% that you are currently dealing with of someone getting to your new cards before they hit your house, activating, and using your cards than this good Samaritan at the gym.

So go ahead and fall for the fear tactics from some answers and put yourself more at risk.

**Note:**  The real risk you run with your wallet laying on the floor at the gym is someone hitting it with a card reader.   They might not even have to touch your wallet and there are ways it is done where you would have a hard time telling on camera.

Comment: A card reader does not help, you cannot "clone" a credit card. You could make three one-off payments up to the limit (3x50 EUR = 150 EUR, and then the owner will get immediately reimbursed when complaining, by EU law). They could create a virtual card on their phone, but there are safeguards (see for instance https://medium.com/@esmund/cloning-nfc-payment-on-mobile-aa9a71106ba5)

Comment: The way I read the question, wallet, keys, and cell phone are left alone in a pile for a short time, but someone took only the wallet and brought it to the front desk, and left the keys and cell phone there. Why would someone do that if they didn't intend to do something with the wallet?

Comment: @ttt: the phone is locked, and can possibly be tracked even if it is off, of little value.  Car keys give you the car, but it’s grand theft auto and unless you know a chop shop, it’s not a great risk vs reward.  Wallet has cash, a 4 year old could get your cash and benefit from it, a 2 year old could get it and throw it in a trash can, the phone could be found, the keys replaced.  The wallet is the most vulnerable thing there.

Comment: @jmoreno hehe. I think you misunderstood my point. This answer suggests that it's normal for a wallet to be returned to the front desk and you shouldn't worry about it. I ask why would someone select just a wallet from the pile and return only that to the front desk if they were just being a good samaritan? In other words, I believe the person had an ulterior motive besides trying to be nice.

Comment: @TTT: no, I understood your point.  I was pointing out reasons why someone might think that a wallet should be turned in, but consider the other items fine.  I would worry little about misplacing a personal device, I would expect it to be either where I left it or at the front desk.  I would be much more worried about a bundle of cash worth the same amount. I would expext it to be untraceably gone.  If I saw a bundle of cash, I would be somewhat concerned about turning it in to the lost  and found. Cash is totally stealable.

Comment: @jmoreno ok. Got it.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the issue with your credit/debit cards, you may be subject to future targeted phishing or identity theft attacks, depending on what's in your wallet. Addresses, pictures, loyalty cards, personal information and such may be used against you to lower your security awareness and/or attempt guesses at passwords and "verification" questions.

Comment: This is unlikely: a targeted phishing attack requires considerable preparation.  Someone who has 30 seconds with your wallet is far more likely to engage in a crime of opportunity: take the cash, memorize the credit cards, and dump the wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Someone COULD have read data from your credit cards.  Either superficially, by reading the numbers, or by scanning the magnetic strip or the chip.

As you immediately notified your bank, you won't directly lose money, even if the details should be used before the cancellation had got through the system.

You might have 'lost' personal information that would be useful in an identity theft.

You might have notified someone that a new credit card would soon be arriving in your post, also a separate letter with the new code.  Post can be stolen.

Comment: haha, yes, if the wallet offers your home address, someone could steal a card, not use it them steal your replacement card.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minor addition to the other good answers, something that *could* happen but you probably *don't* have to worry about.

Here in the Netherlands, our debit cards support [contactless payment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contactless_payment) which, up to a certain amount, doesn't require a PIN code. That amount used to be € 25, but they've increased it to € 50 because of the Covid-19 pandemic (as to reduce the number of times people have to touch the payment terminal). Wikipedia says the United Kingdom has this system too, but I don't know the limits; anyway, I imagine them to be rather low.

In theory, 30 seconds is enough to grab a few snacks or drinks from a vending machine in the same building, but the damage would be very limited in this case (not worth the hassle of replacing your card).

Comment: Here in the UK the limit used to be £30 but, as a result of the Covid-19 Pandemic, they have also upped our limit to £45.

Answer (score 1):

If the thief is prepared, they can easily get the info for each card in your wallet very quickly with a smartphone that has NFC, it would take someone less than 30 seconds to get the info of every card in your wallet.

That's if you have multiple cards in your wallet, if you have a single card the wallet doesn't need to be opened to get the info (which comes with the bonus of appearing to be innocent if the owner is nearby).

The above only applies for a targeted attack, plus if you have an RFID-blocking wallet this attack vector is defeated.

In reality, this comes down to how much you trust people, in my local community when someone loses a wallet, the people that find them will often post in local community groups on social media in an attempt to locate the owner, often with a (censored) photo of one of their cards or IDs that show their name.

**If someone wanted your money, they would've just pocketed your wallet without handing it to anyone or saying anything.**

Answer (score 1):

[Contactless card skimming is a thing.](https://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/beatthescammers/article-5809745/Meet-man-party-trick-nab-card-details.html) Your contactless card can be scanned using any NFC-capable device, such as a smartphone, and then the adversary can use that device to impersonate the card until the contactless limit is reached; usually around 10 transactions before the limit kicks in (the specific number is random each time), with a maximum £45 per transaction. After this, any further attempted transactions will require you to physically insert your card and enter your PIN to reset the limit.

Theoretically, the adversary could just wait for you to make a legitimate transaction and enter your PIN, allowing them to take more money from you, but someone would have noticed by that time: either you would have probably noticed the fraudulent activity by then (e.g. through bank alerts, checking your balance, or discovering that you're overdrawn and a payment won't go through), or your bank almost certainly will have (e.g. due to atypical spending activity and/or transactions occurring near in time but distant in location) and thus suspended your card and/or contacted you.

Answer (score 0):

It is fun to think about scenarios.  These are extremely unlikely but possible.

1. A prepared thief could have replaced your credit cards with counterfeit cards.  You probably called the number on the card to report it lost/stolen.  The counterfeit cards have a number where the thief's confederate pretends to work for the credit card.  He or she may fish for other useful information from you.  You think your card is cancelled, but the thief is now busy using it.
2. Someone could slip a tracking device into your wallet.  Maybe they have a listening device that they can sneak into your wallet.  From now on they know where you are and can listen to your conversations.
3. Someone could have put an envelope of COVID-19 into your wallet.  When you find it, you will get COVID-19.
4. Someone could have replaced your cash with counterfeit bills.  They obtain the value of your cash and if you try to spend your money you may be subject to arrest.